# Google Spreedsheet Maths Date function

Tags: date, math, google-sheets, google-drive-api

ok so in column A i have todays date 18/06/2013 and i want to add 25 days to it, but because i have a list of 100 dates (all different) I need away to do the same thing that

```
=DATE(2013,06,18)+25
```

would do but if you look in open office you can do the same thing by running =A1+25 and that gives you the date in 25 days, in Google that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The TODAY function for Google Spreedsheets returns the current computer system date. The value is updated when your document recalculates. Look at [Google spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en).
Here is an example:

`=TODAY()+25`